# Inline graph notation with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Based on [Notation for flag algebras in graph theory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466408/notation-for-flag-algebras-in-graph-theory), I tried to add arrow to it. I am able to add arrow to notations with 2 nodes by adding `\draw [->] (tmp1) to (tmp2)`. However, I have troubling styling the polygon edges. Any idea how to add arrow to the polygon edges? Thanks!

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{gon/.style={name=tmp,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum
size=10pt,inner sep=0pt},
polygon side/.style args={#1--#2}{
insert path={(tmp.corner #1)-- (tmp.corner #2)}}}
\newcommand{\FlagGraph}[3][]{\ifnum#2=2%
\tikz[baseline=(tmp1)]{\node[circle,inner sep=0.7pt,fill] (tmp1) at (0,0){};
\node[#1,circle,inner sep=0.7pt,fill] (tmp2) at (10pt,0){};
\ifx#3\empty%
\else
\draw[#1] (tmp1) -- (tmp2);
\draw [->] (tmp1) to (tmp2);
\fi}
\else%
\tikz[baseline=(tmp.south)]{\node[#1,gon=#2]{};
\foreach \X in {1,...,#2}{\fill (tmp.corner \X) circle (1pt);}
\draw[#1,polygon side/.list={#3}]}
\fi}
```

Comment: Welcome! Should the arrows be at the ends of the edges or in their middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Here is a minor modification that allows you to attach arrows. (The option to add arrows for the case of two nodes was already implicit in the code you link to, but not documented.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{gon/.style={name=tmp,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum
size=10pt,inner sep=0pt},flag connection/.style={-},
polygon side/.style args={#1--#2}{
insert path={(tmp.corner #1) edge[flag connection] (tmp.corner #2)}}}
%
\newcommand{\FlagGraph}[3][]{\ifnum#2=2%
\tikz[baseline=(tmp1)]{\node[circle,inner sep=0.7pt,fill] (tmp1) at (0,0){};
\node[#1,circle,inner sep=0.7pt,fill] (tmp2) at (10pt,0){};
\ifx#3\empty%
\else
\draw[#1] (tmp1) edge[flag connection] (tmp2);
\fi}
\else%
\tikz[baseline=(tmp.south)]{\node[#1,gon=#2]{};
\foreach \X in {1,...,#2}{\fill (tmp.corner \X) circle (1pt);}
\draw[#1,polygon side/.list={#3}]}
\fi}
\begin{document}
This answer comes with a command 
\[ \texttt{\textbackslash FlagGraph}[\langle\texttt{options}\rangle]\{n\}\{\langle\texttt{connection}~1\rangle,
\langle\texttt{connection}~2\rangle,\dots\}\;,\]
where $n$ denotes the number of corners and the second argument is a list of
connections that are to be drawn. The $\langle\texttt{options}\rangle$ can be
used to change the styles of the edges.

These are some sample graphs: 
\FlagGraph[flag connection/.style={-stealth}]{5}{1--2,1--4} 
\FlagGraph[flag connection/.style={stealth-stealth,red}]{3}{1--2} 
\FlagGraph{2}{1--2} \FlagGraph{2}{}
\FlagGraph[flag connection/.style={-stealth,blue}]{5}{3--1,3--2,3--4,3--5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoom of the graphs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!