# Inline graph notation with labels and colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, graphs, programming

I was writing about flag algebra and came across [Notation for flag algebras in graph theory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466408/notation-for-flag-algebras-in-graph-theory), which gives the code for creating a new command that creates inline graphs. However, I'm unsure how to modify the code so that it will take in more arguments to allow selected vertices to have labels or a different color. Maybe I don't understand the code very well. I am new to latex and have only skimmed parts of the tikz package manual—it is so long... If anyone could help, that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry for not being very clear. Take this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04741.pdf), for instance. I was hoping to create inline graph notations where selected vertices are white (instead of all black, which currently is the default), and some have numbers either next to them or inside them (which would only be visible if the vertex is colored white, I guess). Here are a few screenshots from that paper that might illustrate what I mean. The first screenshot is not inline. I'm only putting it here to show what I mean by partially labeled graphs. But I'm prioritizing being able to specify a color (though I would only need black and white) for the modified new command.
[image: partially labeled graphs]

[image: inline graphs with mixed black and white vertices]

[image: being able to treat the graph as a character to be inserted inside operators and such]

I hope these clarify my questions a little. Thank you again!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The command is surely adjustable. However, it would be nice if you could provide some kind of drawing that shows what you would like to add. For example, where should the labels sit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the solution from a shape (`regular polygon`) to just some circular nodes that are named.

You can access the nodes by the style `every corner` (shortcut: `corners=<to add>`) and `corner <num>`. The same for the vertices: `every vertex` (`vertices=<to add>`) and `vertex <c1>-<c2>`.

There's also `set corners={<corner list>=<styles>}` and `set vertices={<vertices list>=<styles>}` with which you can quickly set the styles of one or multiple corners or vertices with having to write `/.append style` everytime.

With a macro like `\triGraph` macro you don't have to specify `{3}{1-2, 2-3, 3-1}` every time. The same is true for `\biGraph`.
There's also a `\biGraphGround` that internally does a graph with three vertices/corners but doesn't draw the third (upper) corner.
We use this to get the same spacing and vertical picture as the `\triGraph`s.

I've also setup styles that are shortcuts to how the corner circles should be filled (`x` = fill, `o` = no fill).
That way `xox` means that the first and third corner will be filled, the second will not.
The same shortcuts exist for the vertices with `s` = solid and `d` = `d style` that's either `dashed`, `densely dashed` or `densely dotted` in the example below.

That way, the first matrix can be given like so

```
\flaggraphset{size=big,oox}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \triGraph[ddd] + \triGraph[sdd]            
    & \frac {1}{2} (\triGraph[dsd] + \triGraph[ssd]) \\
  \frac {1}{2} (\triGraph[dsd] + \triGraph[ssd])
    & \triGraph[dss]
\end{pmatrix}
```

For all this, I'm introducing a separate [pgfkeys](/questions/tagged/pgfkeys) name space ( `/flaggraph`) instead of using the default `/tikz` so that we don't have any conflicts with other similar named styles.

Instead of `\tikzset{<kv>}`, we now use `\flaggraphset{<kv>}`.

The style `label corners` can be sued to show the names of all corners, but this should only be used to find the number of a certain corner.

The `label 12` style is made for labeling the first and second corner as in your picture.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,stmaryrd}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\downwardoperator}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket_\bullet}
\newcommand*\flaggraphset{\pgfqkeys{/flaggraph}}
\tikzset{
  flag graph/.code=\flaggraphset{#1},
  declare function={angInPolygon(\i,\n)=(\i-1)/\n*360;}}
\flaggraphset{
  tikz/.code=\tikzset{#1},
  vertex path/.style args={#1-#2}{
    insert path={(corner-#1) to (corner-#2)}},
  every corner/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1.5pt},
  every vertex/.style=draw,
  %
  size/.is choice,
  d style/.style=densely dashed,
  size/default/.style={every flaggraph/.append style={
    x=.4em, y=.4em, baseline=-.3em, /flaggraph/corners={minimum size=+1.5pt}}},
  size/big/.style={every flaggraph/.append style={
    x=.55em, y=.55em, baseline=-.6ex, /flaggraph/corners={minimum size=+2.5pt}}},
  size/bigger/.style={d style/.style=dashed, every flaggraph/.append style={thick,
    x=2em, y=2em, baseline=-1.25em, /flaggraph/corners={minimum size=+6pt}}},
  size=default,
  %
  vertex 1-2 horizontal/.style={/tikz/rotate=210},
  % setting all corners/vertices
  corners/.style={/flaggraph/every corner/.append style={#1}},
  vertices/.style={/flaggraph/every vertex/.append style={#1}},
  % setting styles
  set corners/.style args={#1=#2}{
    @/.style={corner ##1/.append style={#2}},@/.list={#1}},
  set vertices/.style args={#1=#2}{
    @/.style={vertex ##1/.append style={#2}},@/.list={#1}},
  % debug
  label corners/.style={corners={label={[/flaggraph/label corner]:\Corner}}},
  label corner/.style={overlay,font=\tiny,gray,inner sep=+0pt}
}

\newcommand*\FlagGraph[3][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[flag graph={#1},/flaggraph/every flaggraph]
  \foreach \Corner in {1,...,#2}
    \node[/flaggraph/every corner, /flaggraph/corner \Corner/.try]
      at ({angInPolygon(\Corner,#2)}:1) (corner-\Corner) {};
  \foreach \Edge in {#3}
    \path[/flaggraph/every vertex, /flaggraph/vertex \Edge/.try,
      /flaggraph/vertex path/.expanded=\Edge];
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*\biGraphGround[1][]{%
  \FlagGraph[vertex 1-2 horizontal,#1,
    corner 3/.append style={draw=none,fill=none}]{3}{1-2}}
\newcommand*\biGraph[1][]{\FlagGraph[#1]{2}{1-2}}
\flaggraphset{% styles for 2-graphs
  oo/.style={corners={fill=none}},xx/.style={corners=fill},
  xo/.style={corner 1/.append style=fill,corner 2/.append style={fill=none}},
  ox/.style={corner 1/.append style={fill=none},corner 2/.append style=fill},
  s/.style={vertices=solid}, d/.style={vertices=/flaggraph/d style},
  label 12/.style={
    corner 1/.append style={label={[inner sep=1pt, font=\small]left:1}},
    corner 2/.append style={label={[inner sep=1pt, font=\small]right:2}}}
}
\newcommand*\triGraph[1][]{\FlagGraph[vertex 1-2 horizontal,#1]{3}{1-2,2-3,3-1}}
\flaggraphset{% styles for 3-graphs
  ooo/.style={corners={fill=none}},xxx/.style={corners=fill},
  oox/.style={set corners={3=fill},set corners={1,2=fill=none}},
  sss/.style={vertices=solid}, ddd/.style={vertices=/flaggraph/d style},
  sdd/.style={set vertices={2-3,3-1=/flaggraph/d style},set vertices={1-2=solid}},
  dss/.style={set vertices={1-2=/flaggraph/d style},set vertices={2-3,3-1=solid}},
  dsd/.style={set vertices={1-2,3-1=/flaggraph/d style},set vertices={2-3=solid}},
  ssd/.style={set vertices={3-1=/flaggraph/d style},set vertices={1-2,2-3=solid}},
  sds/.style={set vertices={2-3=/flaggraph/d style},set vertices={1-2,3-1=solid}},
}
% o = don't fill corner, x = fill corner
% s = solid line,        d = dashed line
\begin{document}
Text: \FlagGraph[set corners={3,5 = red}]{5}{1-2,1-4}\par
Text: \FlagGraph[set corners={2 = blue}]{3}{1-2}\par
Text: \FlagGraph[vertices=bend left]{2}{1-2}\par
Text: \FlagGraph[label corners]{2}{}\par
Text: \FlagGraph[corners=green,
  set vertices={3-1=densely dotted}]{5}{3-1,3-2,3-4,3-5}\par

\[ vv^\top = \flaggraphset{size=big,oox}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \triGraph[ddd] + \triGraph[sdd]            
    & \frac 12 (\triGraph[dsd] + \triGraph[ssd]) \\
  \frac 12 (\triGraph[dsd] + \triGraph[ssd]) & \triGraph[dss]
\end{pmatrix}
\]
and then apply the downward operator to get
\[ \downwardoperator{vv^\top} = \flaggraphset{size=big}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \triGraph[ddd] + \frac 13 \triGraph[sdd]   
    & \frac 13 (\triGraph[sdd] + \triGraph[dss]) \\
  \frac 13 (\triGraph[sdd] + \triGraph[dss]) & \triGraph[dss]
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\begin{center}
\flaggraphset{size=bigger}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
  \biGraphGround[d] &    \biGraphGround[s]     &      \triGraph[ddd]      &     \triGraph[sdd]      & \triGraph[dss] \\
                    & \triGraph[label 12, sdd] & \triGraph[label 12, sds] & \triGraph[label 12,ssd] &
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

% Instead of \textbullet, something like this could be used:
% \FlagGraph[size=big,corners=fill]{1}{}
\flaggraphset{size=big, d style/.style=densely dotted}
These are the \textbullet-flags of sizes 2 and 3:
\biGraph[xo,d], \biGraph[xo], {\flaggraphset{oox}\triGraph[ddd], \triGraph[sdd],
  \triGraph[dsd], \triGraph[dss], and \triGraph[ssd].
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Besides shorthands like `xxx` for the corners, similar shorthands could be defined for the vertices. There's also a solution that would allow us to define the to-be-drawn vertices in a style if there's need for that.

Comment: Thank you for these codes! Quick question: Is it okay to have multiple \tikzset{ ... } set up (for different commands), or should I only have one? Also, when I used the \FlagGraph command to create a 2-vertex (both white and labeled) graph, the vertex circle disappeared (I thought the black contour would remain?), and my single-edge graph was at an angle. Could you let me know what I did wrong with the code? Thank you!          \caption{Let $\mathcal{H}$ be $ \{ \Graph{3}{1--2, 1--3, 2--3} \}$ and $\sigma$ be \FlagGraph[label corners, corner 1/.style=white, corner 2/,style=white]{2}{1-2}\par }

Comment: \Graph is from the post I referred to earlier—I changed its name. I know it works okay I have tested it before. Thank you for catching that mistake! Do you mean this:  $\sigma$ be \FlagGraph[label corners, fill = none]{2}{1-2}\par? Somehow it's still giving me black vertices... Also, what do you think about the angle? How can I get it to be horizontal?

Comment: That solves the color problem! One last thing: the single edge is at a 30-degree angle with the horizontal line. Do you know how I can make the single-edge graph completely horizontal? I think your 4th output also has two vertices, but they are at the same level. I wonder why the outputs are different given that we are using the same new command?

Comment: @Severus2013 I've updated my answer with the examples of your pictures. With a few simple styles we have handy shortcuts to change the style of the lines and of the nodes. I've also moved the keys in a separate `PGFkeys` namespace to avoid clashes.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of these! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Tikz already has a way to draw graphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs}
\tikzgraphsset{
empty nodes,
nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt},
counterclockwise, radius=6pt, phase=210,
}
\tikzset{
%baseline=0pt,
every label/.style={font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt},
dashed/.style={dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt},
label distance=1pt,
}
\begin{document}
~\\Example 1 \tikz \graph[n=3] {1,2,3;1--2--3--1};\\~\\
example 2 in math:
\( \mathcal{H} = \tikz \graph[n=3] {1["1"'left],2["2"'right],3[fill]; 1--[dashed]2--3--[dashed]1}; \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Text and math with small graphs]

**Edit:**

From OP comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs}
\tikzgraphsset{
empty nodes,
nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt},
counterclockwise, radius=6pt, phase=210,
}
\tikzset{
baseline=-2pt,
every label/.style={font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt},
dashed/.style={dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt},
label distance=1pt,
}
\begin{document}
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be \tikz \graph[n=3]{1,2,3;1--2,1--3,2--3}; and $\sigma$ be \tikz \graph[n=3] {1,2,3;2["2"'right],1["1"'left];1--2};
\end{document}
```

[image: Text and small triangular graphs]

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing that out! I didn't know Tikz already has a graph library. Do you know what source would be the best place to start reading up on it? Also, I tried to imitate your code but got an undefined control sequence error. Here is the part of the code that gave me an error:                               \caption{Let $\mathcal{H}$ be $ \{ \Graph{3}{1--2, 1--3, 2--3} \}$ and $\sigma$ be \tikz \graph[n=2] {2["2"'right],1["1"'left]; 1--2}; }. It's the part after "$\sigma$". Also, is it okay to have multiple \tikzset{ ... } set up (for different commands) or should I only have one?

Comment: The best place to read about all(most) TikZ things is in the manual. The manual is huge, but just read the relevant chapter. Do not type so many new things without testing - test one graph at a time, you miss `/tikz`, use wrong parentheses and more - see edit.

Comment: You meant this https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-tikz, right? Somehow I'm still getting the undefined control sequence error. But I'll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - That look like an online version of the TikZ manual. If you have LaTeX installed on your computer, you already have the manual. Just type `texdoc tikz` in a terminal. Can you compile the code from my edit?

Comment: I've been using the online overleaf editor. Do you think it would be worth installing LaTex? The interesting thing is that when I compile your code on a separate file, it works. But when I put it in my main file where I need it, it doesn't. How is that possible? I mean, my main file was compiling before I added your code, which does compile if left on its own on a separate file. Also, when I tweaked your code to make a single-edge graph (both vertices white and labeled), the edge I get is at a 30-degree angle from the horizontal line. Do you know how I can make it completely horizontal?

Comment: The `phase=210` and `counterclockwise` (instead of `clockwise`) is put in to make the numbering of a three node graph align with your given "1" and "2". The phase is problematic for a two cell node. Comment out `empty nodes` to see what I mean. It is time to create a Minimal Working Example showing your problem and ask new questions. Copy your main file and delete *everything* unneeded to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can still use the code as is, and then for two node graph use `\tikz \graph[n=2, phase=180]...`

Comment: It's working in my main file now—I removed some other commands that I think were clashing with each other. Thank you so much!